# On-the-fly JavaScript function vs inital

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm developing an jQuery plugin that designs selectboxes. ATM all HTML is created and than hided when document is ready. when user clicks, the created code will be shown. But because I'm breaking W3C rules ( will be hidden and wrapped inside  that has  inside (block level element inside inline)) and I'm wondering maybe I should create -based option list on-the-fly and append it to . is it bad? Slow? Bad/good practice?

Thanks!

Sample code:

HTML:

```
<p>
<select>
    <option value="1">Value</option>
    <option value="2">Value</option>
</select>
</p>
```

After document ready:

```
<p>
<span class="selectwrap">
    <a tabindex="0" class="select">Value</a>
    <ul class="selectbox" style="display: block;">
        <li>value</li>
        <li>value</li>
    </ul>
    <select style="display: none;">
        <option value="1">Value</option>
        <option value="2">Value</option>
    </select>
</span>
</p>
```

Comment: You can't put a `ul` inside a `p` like that.

Comment: I know, but once the valid document is loaded, JS will generate this for each select. The question is is it OK to generate code for each select element once the document is loaded or should i generate code for specific select when user clicks on one.

Comment: Depends. My first question is whether or not there's a good reason not to generate it on the client side. My second question is whether or not there's a good reason to generate invalid HTML, when there's a `div` tag made for doing stuff like this. *Then* I'd ask whether or not the select should be generated on initial load, or on-demand. If there's no reason to send the selects if the user never does anything with the selectbox then it probably doesn't matter, but it also depends on how many there are.

Comment: 1) it is good idea, i dont wanna bloat my html with "pretty" select's HTML, I want javascript to do it.
2) DIV tag creates just as invalid HTML, because select can be within any inline element. So it's something you just have to deal with.
3) I'd do on-the fly thing but maybe it makes aover-all iteraction slower

I already went with on-the fly option, this way even the Javascript wont create invalid code, cause Ul will be added to the end of document and only while user has cliecked on select.

Thanks!

Comment: 1) It's not bloat to do it on the server, you're already contemplating generating it all at once via JavaScript--it's the same. I'm asking *why* on the client. 2) The select isn't the problem, the `ul` is. 3) Not significantly slower--plus it's hidden, so the chances of the user noticing *anything* are basically zero. And the JS can put the select anywhere, whether all at once or on-the-fly.

Comment: Creating meaningless html just to make something pretty is hacking that bloats the code ... But thanks for you time! On pageload JS will design pretty select and adds trigger on them. If user clicks on it, JS will generate UL from the hidden select. when user closes select, the hidden select will be updated to selected value and UL will be removed from the DOM. :)

Answer (score 0):

If your document structure is invalid, it doesn't matter when you create it or if it is hidden, it is still invalid. So fix the document structure first then work out how best to show and hide it. Perhaps you can post a minimal example of the markup.

It is generally a good idea to minimise client side processing, so don't start doing things on the client just because you can, particularly if it doesn't provide any benefits.